# Are the branches of the Lambert W function disjoint?

Tags: lambert-w

On the Wikipedia side on the Lambert W function it says "The functions $W_k(z), k ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ are all injective and their ranges are disjoint."
Is there any other source to find that information about the disjointness of the branches? Ich would like to read more about it, but didn't find anything helpful by googeling it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: There is a section on branches [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf), starting at the bottom of p. 341.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thank you very much!